# Cancel button not shown in Azure AD B2C Sign-in dialog

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How do I get a Cancel button shown in the default Azure AD B2C sign-in UI that is displayed when I do a redirect login using the combined sign-in/sign-up policy?
[image]

The Cancel button should redirect the user back to the calling page in my Angular 4 SPA.  Is this possible to do without using a custom page layout for the signIn/signUp policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.  You have to use a custom page.

FYI, the sign-up only policy has a cancel button.  The sign-up page in a sign-in/sign-up policy has a cancel button.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. And it is not on the initial page of the sign-in policy either.  Any idea why it is this way? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I don't.  Hopefully, someone from MSFT can chime in as to why that is.

Comment: I have opened an [Azure improvement idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31668049-add-cancel-button-to-azure-ad-b2c-signin-and-combi) for this.  Please up-vote it if you agree that this is a problem.