# B2C Custom Policies: Add a cancel button to the sign in page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I want to have a "cancel" button on my SignIn page. This feature is not available by default, there is a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31668049-add-cancel-button-to-azure-ad-b2c-signin-and-combi) for it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472428/cancel-button-not-shown-in-azure-ad-b2c-sign-in-dialog) suggests that it can be achieved using a custom page. My question is: How? I tried modifying our custom HTML, but was unable to get the UI to show it. I want it to behave like the "cancel" that is available during sign up and password reset.

So far, we only had the default placeholder:

```html
<custom HTML>
...
                <div id="api" data-name="Unified">
                </div>
...
<custom HTML>
```

After looking at [this example](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-AzureBlobStorage-Client/blob/master/sample_templates/contoso/EmailVerification.html), I tried something like this:

```
<custom HTML>
...
        <div id="api" data-name="Unified">
          <div class="buttons">
              <button id="continue">
                  Continue
              </button>
              <button id="cancel">
                  Cancel
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
...
<custom HTML>
```

The buttons are not rendered. If I move them out of the placeholder, they are shown, but don't do anything. We are using custom policies.

As an example, I started fresh by using the [custom policies starter pack (local accounts)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts).

[image]

I was able to get a cancel button to show up in this example by changing the orchestration step type. This removes the ability to sign up, and it no longer works if I need an identity provider selection.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
```

> Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_XXX" of tenant "xxx.onmicrosoft.com".User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_xxx" of tenant "xxx.onmicrosoft.com" has step 2 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Adding HTML inside of the API element will not help- the contents of the API div are not yours, assume IEF/B2C have control over that, though you can use CSS and some JavaScript to alter predictable elements that will be rendered.

In your custom policy, locate the Self-Asserted Technical Profile you are using to display the Sign Up page. Locate the Metadata block for the TP and check to see if it has the following entry:

```
<Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
```

If that value is there, it would explain the absence of the Cancel button. The default behavior of that setting is "true" ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata)), so if it is omitted, there may be something else at play - it would be helpful if you were to copy your Self Asserted Technical Profile section's contents to provide some initial troubleshooting...

Comment: You can take the custom policies starter pack as an example. I want a cancel button on the very first page. I will add some more information to the question. There is no setting present that disables the cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I don't need "sign up" or a ClaimsProviderSelection, it seems like I can just switch the type of the orchestration step. I was unable to get a valid policy if I need a ClaimsProviderSelection.

**This does not fully solve my problem**, since I need at least the possibility to have a social login in addition to local account. Password reset is also gone...

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Change the first line to:

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. As in the other answers the features of the content definitions are mutual exclusive. If you have password reset and signup (as in **unified** templates), you won't get Cancel, and if you use **selfasserted**, you can cancel but not signup.

Use this code (outside the `<div id="api">` part!):

```
<div class="buttons">
 <button id="cancel" onclick="window.location = 'https://yourtarget.com'">
  Cancel
 </button>
</div>
```

The CSS will render the button just fine. Also, JavaScript must be allowed. In your relying party definition add it (`<ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>`) like this:

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      ....
```

Please note that adding the button outside the "api" fragment will exclude it from any sort of localization. I personally prefer controlling the screens by  myself and usually use Razor pages to deliver the HTML. That way I can control how to handle the elements and design outside the generated "api" section much better. The definition on *TrustFrameworkBase.xml* will look like this, then (see **LoadUri**):

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">               
<LoadUri>https://yourserver.com/Identity/SignInSignUp</LoadUri>
<RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.5</DataUri>
<Metadata>
 <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
</Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your content definition `"api.signuporsignin`", it may using the `DataUri` of any of the following:

```
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssd:1.2.0

urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0
```

If you want a cancel button by default then you need to use a self asserted `DataUri` like
`urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0`
Then by default the **Cancel** button will show up. If using custom UI you have to push the **Cancel** button using JavaScript into the from and decide what should happen when the button got clicked.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. However, if I do this then "reset password" and "signup" disappear, like in my screenshot below.

Comment: Yes, bcoz that DataURI (unifiedssp) is handling those links and UI elements. If you require them them then add the **Cancel** button using javascript

Comment: Yeah, I have trouble doing that. Not so much with having a button appear, but what it should actually do. I don't really know where to "go" after all. There are multiple applications and native apps using the B2C policy. Can I use JavaScript to acually trigger B2Cs "User canceled the self assertion" event or something similar?